# Maclaurin series approximation

Tags: calculus, integration

So, I've been running through some of these problems in my text book and was fine until I came across a Maclaurin series of a definite integral.

$$\int_0^{1/2}\tan^{-1}(2x^2) dx$$

from the table in the book I know that

$$\int\tan^{-1}(2x^2) dx = \sum_0^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(2x^2)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$$

Is it just as simple as plugging $2x^2$ in for $x$.

Am I supposed to integrate this first or just evaluate the sum as $1/2$ and $0$?

Comment: Well, for typesettings, use `tan^{-1}` instead of `tan^-1`.

Comment: Thanks! Any clue why (2k+1) as an exponent shows up strange?

Comment: What you can do is to start with the series for the arctangent, replace the variable with $2x^2$, and then integrate termwise...

Comment: @PatrickM It's because you could have fit all the equation code into a single block: `$ L.H.S = R.H.S $`. :)

Comment: @Frenz, no, it's because OP did not enclose his exponents within braces. Compare $x^-1$ (`x^-1`) with $x^{-1}$ (`x^{-1}`).

Comment: @J.M. Oh, turns out you're right, but using `$ sth. $ = $ sth. $ $ factor $` is as weird, I suppose.

Comment: $\int_0^.5 \dfrac{(2x^2)^1}{1!} + \dfrac{(2x^2)^3}{3!} + \dfrac{(2x^2)^5}{5!} + \dfrac{(2x^2)^7}{7!} + ... dx$

Leaves me with...

$\dfrac{2x^3}{3*1!} + \dfrac{8x^7}{7*3!} + \dfrac{32x^11}{11*5!} + \dfrac{128x^15}{15*7!} + ... ]_0^.5$

Comment: Didn't expect it to submit that when I inserted a line break. From there I can plug in x=1/2 and evaluate it and that would result in my approximate sum?

Comment: Patrick: Yes. ${}$

Answer (score 1):

The series $\arctan z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$ is valid for $|z| <1$. If $x \in [0, \frac{1}{2}]$, then $2x^2 \in [0,\frac{1}{2}]$, so we can integrate the series with $z=2 x^2$ term by term.

So plug $z=2x^2$ into the series, and integrate over $[0, \frac{1}{2}]$.